# time out error using entity framework?

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

We have the following code:

```
var db = new CoreEntityDB();
var abc = new abcDB();
var connection = new DataStore(db.ConnectionStrings.First(p => p.Name == "Abc").Value, DataStore.Server.SqlServer);
var projects = new List<abc_Employees>();
projects.AddRange(abc.Database.SqlQuery<abc_Employees>("usp_ABC_EmployeeSys"));
```

The project is failing on the following line:

```
projects.AddRange(abc.Database.SqlQuery<abc_Employees>("usp_ABC_EmployeeSys"));
```

And the error says: "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"

Everything was working fine a few days ago, and now, nothing. Nothing's changed either as far as code, or sql stored proc.

Anyone else experienced this before?

Comment: Is your database server running?   I get this sometimes when I just booted and I run a page before SQL Server has had a change to spin up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run SP independently to see if that's the bottle neck?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the command that is timing out?

You can increase the command timeout using:
`((IObjectContextAdapter)abc).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;`

You should take a look at your stored procedure. The default timeout is 30 seconds so it looks like it is taking longer for the stored procedure to return results. Increasing the timeout is just treating the symptoms.